# Get timeframe for 09:00 EST to 16:00 EST in PINE script version 5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am new to PINE script. I am trying to build a logic where it checks if the timeframe is within 09:00 EST to 16:00 EST. I tried using 'time(timeframe.period, "0930-1600:23456")' but the issue is that different markets are on different timezones (Ex: SPY is EST and ES is CST). Also, I had the intention to make it robust so that it can be used from anywhere in the world (irrespective of user's timezone) it should refer to 09:00 EST to 16:00 EST on a given day.

I tired counting bars backwards keeping resolution in mind but it didn't work. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using 'time(timeframe.period, "0930-1600:23456")'

`time` also has a third parameter, `timezone`, which allows you to specify the timezone for the time passed to the second parameter. It accepts both fixed offsets (e.g., `"UTC-4"`) and identifiers from the [IANA tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). In your case, the second option might be better because these timezone specifications also include daylight savings, and the timezone specification in question would be `"America/New_York"`.

The code below highlights the bars that are between the 0930-1600 Monday-Friday based on the New York time, no matter what the timezone of the symbol is.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
isInSession = time(timeframe.period, "0930-1600:23456", "America/New_York")
bgcolor(not na(isInSession) ? color.new(color.green, 85) : na)
```